# Is there any verse in which the Quran narrates about the divorce of a real person?

Tags: quran, talaq

Is there any case or narration in the Quran that tells about the divorce / the event of divorcing of a Prophet or any Real (Existed) Person, **OTHER THAN** the one told in Al Ahzab 33:37?

I'm not asking about verses that tells about the RULES related to divorce.  I'm asking only for verses that narrates about the event of divorce of someone.

Post as many examples as you can with, of course, reference to the Surah(s) and Verse(s). Note also that I'm asking for Quranic references only.

Comment: Some verses on rulings might have been revealed on the event of an actual divorce among the Muslims.

Comment: Yes, but you mean "might"?  I'm asking a verse in the Quran that actually is telling that it did happen to somebody specific..I'm quite sure that divorces did happen back then...but to who? Which verse of the quran relates to that?

Answer (score 1):

In Surah albagara (the second surah), from verse [226 to 237](https://quran.com/2/226-237).

And there is surah called divorce (in Arabic tlag) it is number is [65](https://quran.com/65/) and it has 12 verses.

Comment: Would it be possible to pinpoint exactly where a real person is divorced within these verses?

Comment: i didn't understand you

Comment: "I'm not asking about verses that tells about the RULES related to divorce." what part of this did you not understand?